# Looking for a more elegant way to check for nullable value types

Tags: c#, nullable, value-type

To check if a value type is nullable I'm currently doing something like this:

```
int? i = null;
bool isNullable = i.GetType().ToString().Contains("System.Nullable");
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx) - that will return `null` if it's not a nullable type to start with, or the underlying value type otherwise:

```
if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null)
{
    // Yup, t is a nullable value type
}
```

Note that this uses the `Nullable` static class, rather than the `Nullable<T>` structure.

Comment: +1 Id probably go with this one since its a lot cleaner, plus looking at Reflector, this also checks to make sure the type is not a generic type definition.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
{
  // it is a nullable type
}
```

This is how Microsoft recommends you [Identify Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx)

Comment: Wow - that's a strange recommendation for Microsoft to make given that there's a built-in method to do this. (See my answer.)

Comment: Yeah it seems a bit more long winded. Looking at yours, could it be that it returns null if its not a nullable type and that although you can use it to check if a type is nullable it's not strictly meant for that purpose? (although it is quicker!)

Comment: @w69wrdy: Well it gives more information than you require - but it gives you all the information you *do* require and in a simpler way. It's *very slightly* less efficient in the case where it's a nullable type, as it'll also get the generic type arguments... but I'd go for readability and simplicity any day.

Answer (score 0):

```
int? i;
bool isNullable = i is Nullable;
```

**Edit**: Nevermind, this doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I get this compiler warning:
The given expression is never of the provided ('System.Nullable') type

Comment: @RobSullivan: Yes, it's checking for compatibility with the System.Nullable static class... which is never going to work. I've been assuming you've got an instance of `Type` btw - if you've got an *actual variable* with a concrete type then you already know the result...